# Obtener ultimo día del mes en curso

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

Estoy intentando sacar el ultimo día del mes en curso desde un datetimepicker.

```
var

 dia, mes, anio : Word;
 fecha_actual, fecha : TDateTime;
begin
 fecha_actual := Now;
 DecodeDate(fecha_actual,anio,mes,dia);
 fecha := EncodeDate(anio,mes,31);
 DateTimePicker.DateTime := fecha;
end;
```

El problema es cuando estoy en un mes cuyo días son 28 o 30 o en un año bisiesto
me aparece este mensaje "invalid argument to date encode".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema, tal y como te has encontrado, es que no todos los meses tienen 31 días. Dado que el sistema si conoce esa información te recomiendo cambiar la estrategia para aprovecharlo. 
Obtén el primer día del mes siguiente y restale 1 día utilizando las funciones existentes. El sistema calculará correctamente si el día anterior al 1 del mes siguiente es 28, 30 o 31.

```
var
 dia, mes, anio : Word;
 fecha_actual, fecha : TDateTime;
begin
 fecha_actual := Now;
 DecodeDate(fecha_actual,anio,mes,dia);

 // Caso especial en que haya que incrementar el año también
 if mes=12 then
   fecha := EncodeDate(anio+1,1,1)
 else
    fecha := EncodeDate(anio,mes+1,1);

 DateTimePicker.Date := IncDay(fecha, -1);
end;
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba.Gracias Germán

Answer (score 3):

La RTL de Delphi trae la unidad DeteUtils, que tiene una serie de rutinas ya listas para realizar diversas tareas o cálculos con fechas.

Una de esas es `EndOfAMonth`, que recibe como parámetros el año y el mes que te interesa.

Para dejar el último día del mes en el DateTimePicker1 basado en la fecha seleccionada, puedes intentar esto:

```
use DateUtils

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DateTimePicker1.Date := EndOfAMonth(YearOf(DAteTimePicker1.Date), MonthOf(DateTimePicker1.Date));
end;
```

Un saludo.